# Liferay 6.1 pagination

Tags: search, pagination, liferay

I'm trying to add pagination in a custom Liferay portlet (6.1). I list the results afer another portlet makes a search, so the content depend on the terms of the search. I tried to use the liferay-ui:search-container tag, but I found a problem:

Let's suppose I make a search and it returns 13 results, delta is set to 5, so the results have to be shown in 3 different pages.
If I make another search and it returns me less than 10 results (I need less than 3 pages to show them), the portlet with the search container tells me that there aren't any results to show (because I am in the 3rd page).
I observed that the problem is the field "cur", which is not resetted after a new search. I tried to do it on myself, but the SearchContainer type does not provide the setCur() method.

How can I set that field?

Answer (score 0):

How are you creating searchContainer object in jsp? You can create a searchcontainer object which takes defaultcur as one of its constructor arguments. That should solve your problem.